# How to create a shortcut to files/folders in kali linux?

Tags: debian, kali-linux

How to create a shortcut to files/folders like I can do in windows. Is there no such feature in Kali-Linux? Or do I need a third-party software to do so?

Comment: You can use `ln` command.

Comment: Why are some people marking this as a duplicate question to "Why is Kali Linux so hard to set up? Why won't people help me?". Anyone with common sense can tell that those are two different questions, that aren't even related to each other.

Comment: It is because this is very basic command of linux. You would find tons of tuts on Internet.

Comment: @slm, how would you handle this question if it didn’t mention Kali?

Comment: @StephenKitt - You want to strip the kali references off this and answer it? It's not a bad question to add to the site w/o any Kali references.

Answer (score 2):

In any Linux (and Unix), you can use the comand ln - make links between files (and dirs)

Example:

`ln -s /tmp/ ~/Desktop/tmp`

Make the "shorcut" to /tmp in your Desktop